# What is the difference between dispersion and mean root square deviation?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, statistics, standard-deviation

So the question is why do we have mean root square deviation (standard deviation)? 
Isn't it enough just to use only such characteristic as dispersion?
Why is root square deviation (standard deviation) used if we already have dispersion?

I'd be very happy to discuss this topic with you, guys!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think they are same

Comment: You would need a definition of *dispersion*.  Standard deviation is [one of many possibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion#Measures) each with its own advantages and disadvantages

Answer (score 3):

The correct term is "root mean square", not "mean root square". "Dispersion" is a broad term: standard deviation is one measure of dispersion; mean absolute deviation is another; interquartile range is another, and so on. The main reason for using root-mean-square deviation is this:
\begin{align}
& \text{If } X_1,\ldots,X_n \text{ are independent} \\[6pt]
& \text{then } \operatorname{var}(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \operatorname{var}(X_1) + \cdots+\operatorname{var}(X_n).
\end{align}

Comment: Please be so kind, tell me what is var? What does it mean in math, maybe variable or not? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: @DannyLego : "var" = "variance", i.e. mean square. The square root of the variance is the standard deviation, i.e. the root-mean-square deviation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback!!!
Would you be so kind as to explain what does the formula means?
Or maybe how to make the formula easier to understand if possible?

Comment: @DannyLego : Say you toss a coin. The number of "heads" you get is either $0$ or $1,$ with equal probability. The standard deviation is $1/2$ and the variance is $1/4.$ Next you toss $100$ coins. The number of heads you get is in the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,100\}.$ The expected value is $50$ and the variance is $$ \underbrace{\frac 1 4 +  \cdots + \frac 1 4}_{100 \text{ terms}} = 25, $$ so the standart deviation is $\sqrt{25} = 5.$ That is how the equality in my answer above can be used.

Comment: Thanks, now starting to understand something...

One more question (Maybe it is stupid to ask, but do me a favour please) If a teacher during my future math exam will ask me the question (he is going to ask, I know!): '' Why is root mean square widely used if dispersion already exists?'' Can I answer '' Because If X1,…,Xn are independent then var(X1+⋯+Xn)=var(X1)+⋯+var(Xn)'' and add your example about coins, would it be full answer? What do you think?
Or how would you answer if you were me?))

Sorry for stupid questions one more time, but it is extremely important for me.

Comment: I would write something like that.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for using the sample variance $S^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2}{n-1}$ is that $E(S^2) = \sigma^2,$ the population variance.  The technical terminology is that $S^2$ is an *unbiased estimator* of $\sigma^2.$ 
You may want to look at a [*formal proof*](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~axt12/415s07/material/3.%20The%20sample%20variance%20is%20an%20unbiased%20estimator%20) of this. [However, the sample standard
deviation $S$ is not unbiased, we
have $E(S) < \sigma.$ That is, on average the sample standard deviation $S$ slightly underestimates the population standard deviation $\sigma.$ Especially for small sample sizes $n,$ the shortfall may be noticeable. For $n = 10$ normal observations $E(S) \approx 0.94\sigma;$ but for $n=25,$ it's $E(S) \approx 0.99\sigma.$]

Moreover, for
normal data, $S^2$ is the 'best' estimate of the population variance, according to widely accepted criteria for 'goodness'.

Also for normal data, one has
$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1).$ This provides a
convenient method to make *confidence intervals* which give an idea
how far from $\sigma^2$ the estimate $S^2$ might be.

By contrast, a major disadvantage of $S^2$ is that it is very sensitive to values of $X_i$ that are far from $\bar X.$ One unusually large 'deviation' from the mean
$X_i - \bar X$ can cause $S^2$ itself to be unusually large. That is the
reason one sometimes uses the other measures of dispersion mentioned in the Answer by @MichaelHardy. (The mean absolute deviation and interquartile
range are sometimes called *robust* measures of dispersion.)

As an analogy, you may already be familiar with two different measures of 'centrality',
the sample mean and sample median. The mean is often used, but there are
situations in which the median is better.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that *dispersion* is a generic term thus there is no specific formula. You cannot compute *the* dispersion.

Wikipedia currently lists seven different estimators of dispersion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion#Measures) among which the standard deviation, obviously. One or the other can be preferred for some property such as efficiency, robustness, ease of computation...